# "No resource found that matches the given name"

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I have a big console full of errors, all the same errors.

```
[2015-02-07 08:33:42 - TheHunter] C:\Users\Windows 8\workspace\TheHunter\res\drawable-hdpi\custom2.xml:4: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/button2').

[2015-02-07 08:33:42 - TheHunter] C:\Users\Windows 8\workspace\TheHunter\res\drawable-hdpi\custom3.xml:4: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/button3').
```

I have those same errors but for different images about 100 times in my console.
This is just a little bit of my code for my main page, I have several buttons and images being used but keep having all the same errors. I see all the images it just wont allow me to use the app in the android emulator due to these errors.

Could you please tell me why am I getting these errors? Thanks.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:context="com.application.thehunter.MainActivity" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="74dp"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:background="@drawable/custom1"
        android:src="@drawable/Button1"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText,ContentDescription" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:background="@drawable/custom2"
        android:src="@drawable/Button2"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText,ContentDescription" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe capital is part of the problem.  Resource names must be lowercase, numeric, or underscore beginning with a letter.  Also double check that you actually do have files named that.